# Random access cyclical data structure with two defined operations

Tags: c, algorithm

As input I recive a list of natural integers. 
I have to store them inside a structure that enables me to go from the last element to the first without much problem.

The task is to perform t (number given from the start) operations on this data structure. Starting from the first number given as input (i=0):

If data[i] % 2 == 0  -> perform operation R

else -> perform operation X

operation R: remove element with index position i+1, and move to the right as many times as was the value of removed element.

operation X: take the value of data[i] element and insert new element in front of that one with value data[i]-1. Then move data[i] times to the right.

example (i->n means that i points to el. with value n):

input: 3 1 2 3

t = 3

data = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

```
 1.
 i->1
 operation X, 
 result: [ 1, 0, 2, 3 ]

 2.
 i->0
 operation R,
 result: [ 1, 0, 3 ]

 3.
 i->1
 operation X, 
 result: [ 1, 0, 0, 3 ]
```

The real problem occurs when the value of t is very large. 
I tried two implementations:

- One based on linked list. I know it works because the result is correct, but execution time is close to 2-3 minutes.
- One based on an array but the execution time is just a little faster.

Here is the fragment that takes 99,99% of execution time:

```
while(t--){
    c = current -> value;
    if(c % 2 == 0){
        c = current -> next -> value;
        Node* n = current -> next -> next;
        free(current -> next);
        current -> next = n;

        --size;
    }
    else{
        Node* n = getNode(current -> next);
        current -> next = n;
        n -> value = c-1;

        ++size;
    }

    c %= size;
    while(c--){
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

getNode(Node* n)  returnes new node with node -> next = n.

Any insight into optimalization method/ other approach appreciated.

*edit:

```
Node* getNode(Node* nxt){
    Node* first = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    first -> value = -1;
    first -> next = nxt;
    return first;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the faster implementation.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Can you see any optimalization method? Because execution time should be closer to 1s. than 2 minutes.

Comment: It's exactly the same logic just implemented with an array. Can there be any other logic?

Comment: Did you compile with full optimisation?

Comment: How does `getNode()` look like?

Comment: I have no control over optimalization parameters - this is an online platform task. (something like SPOJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking in terms of the algorithm run-time (where n is the length of elements):

- You need `t` operations, so outside loop is `O(n)`
- If you use linked lists, finding ith element is `O(n)` and moving the `ith` element around is `Theta(1)` as you are just changing the pointers making your inner while loop `O(n)` so total runtime of `O(n^2)`
- With array, finding ith element is `Theta(1)` but moving them around is `O(n)`, so inner loop is again `O(n)`, total being `O(n^2)`

Can you use a hashmap with integer index as the key and value working as if it's a linked list? Hashmaps will make both the search and move `Theta(1)` making the total `O(n)`

Comment: Thanks very much for this suggestion. I can write this program in c++ so there is such possibility. (not that it can't be done in C)

Answer (score 0):

A few more observations:

- The data structure can grow.
- For each odd number `X` implies a `R` statement is inserted (`data[i]-1` will be even).
- The max size of the 'intermediary result' is `2 * N`, with `N` being the number of elements in the original input (when the input is only odd numbers).

Optimisations:

1. You can therefore optimise a little by using an array of structs, so you never have to call `free()`. Instead, use a bit of bookkeeping state in each struct to mark an element as active/inactive. Possibly simply checking if the value `>= 0` to determine whether or not it is valid/inactive. You will need to compensate for this in your navigation/seeking code, because now you need more than simple modulo arithmetic to navigate from the current index to the next element. The downside is that this makes `X` more expensive because the same holds for navigating to the previous element.
2. You can further reduce seeking behaviour in the array by tracking the previous position of the current index. This helps avoid the penalty of implementing `X` incurred by step #1.
3. You can trivially optimise by checking whether or not `size >= 0` in your outer loop (`while(t--)`) because if `size` is 0 before `t` is you are done anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Will surly try Aditya's solution and take your hints under consideration while doing this.